# Extract x,y coordinates from arbitrary SVG path with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, svg

I want to replace the coordinates within a SVG path with variables. (with javascript). While svg path could be of many types it would be of great help to get some support on a concrete example:

```
d = "M27,0C27,21,4,34,-13,23C22,18,-27,9,-27,0";
```

I want this SVG path to be transformed into

```
var x = [];
var x[0] = 27; x[1] = ...

d = "M + x[0] + "," + y[0] 
    + "C" 
    + x[0] + "," + y[0] + ","
    + x[1] + "," + y[1] + ","
    + x[2] + "," + y[2] + ","
    + "C" 
    + x[3] + "," + y[3] + ","
    + x[4] + "," + y[4] + ","
    + x[5] + "," + y[5];
```

So my problem is to find the proper javascript RegExp to extract all the variables and by use of it generate the SVG path as given.

What I actually do is creating a Javascript object representing a given svg and I want to able to set the coordinates individually.

Any help highly appreciated

thx, martin

UPDATE:
next to the accepted answer there is also a very handy method in the wonderful raphael.js library to analyze a SVG path

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.parsePathString

Comment: Just split it by comma and use individual items from resulting array.

Comment: Thanks, problem is 23C22 with which kind of starts things getting messy. (and of course here i have only a simple svg path example)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scripting <path> data in SVG (reading and modifying)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053487/scripting-path-data-in-svg-reading-and-modifying)

Comment: Thanks Robert, that link for sure includes what i was looking for. Can you please post as an answer so I can approve it. That makes it more likely that people who stumble over this question find the link. Thanks agai

Comment: raphaeljs link is broken.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use the SVG DOM to parse it [there are more details in this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053487/scripting-path-data-in-svg-reading-and-modifying) but basically you do

```
var segments = path.pathSegList;
```

and that gives you an array of segments and values you can read or write e.g.

```
segments.getItem(0).y = -10;
```

Comment: Alternative for deprecated SVG pathSegList http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352624/alternative-for-deprecated-svg-pathseglist

Answer (score 2):

This could be your regex:

```
var newd = d.match(/(^[0-9]+,)|(^,[0-9]+)$/g);
var arrayd = newd.split(",");
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately not that easy as the path can contain "23C22" nasty things like that (start of a new cubic spline)

Comment: What variables do you want to create from "23C22", f.e.

Comment: 23 is the y[2] variable in the above example, C stands as it is an 22 will be the x[3] variable

Comment: thx a lot - as Robert Longson kindly gave a more complete answer I accepted his answer - thanks again

Comment: Yes but that answer no longer works thanks to deprecation, and I for one am not getting on with trying to use the mentioned alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning JavaScript so I'm unable to help with the transforming thing, but this regex should help:

```
\-?\d+
```

It captures all of the coordinates from the string you have provided, while avoiding characters `[a-zA-Z]`.

But I can provide some **more-or-less** code in **Java** which would do the job.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.Compile("\-?\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourPathString);
while(m.Find())
    \\add the match to your new table or something you want
```

Comment: thanks - as I got an answer for my overall problem I accepted that answer and don't have to implement it myself - thanks again

Comment: That was an answer for your overall problem but not the exact question you asked. These attempts to answer your original question , when you thought you would have to parse the string yourself, are still credit-worthy. They might be useful to others that browsed here. Your preferred solution has been deprecated and no longer works, by the way.