# Alternative for deprecated SVG pathSegList

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm writing a Leaflet plugin that extends the polyline functionality. In the my plugin I'm accessing the path segments using the SVGPathSegList interface. But according to the Chrome DevTools the interface will be removed in Chrome 48. I'm seeking for another possibility to access the the path segments.

[image: Chrome DevTools notification]

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/1dy6s79g/) my fiddle.

```
(function () {
    var __onAdd = L.Polyline.prototype.onAdd,
        __onRemove = L.Polyline.prototype.onRemove,
        __updatePath = L.Polyline.prototype._updatePath,
        __bringToFront = L.Polyline.prototype.bringToFront;

    L.Polyline.include({
      onAdd: function (map) {
          __onAdd.call(this, map);
          this._textRedraw();
      },

      onRemove: function (map) {
          __onRemove.call(this, map);
      },

      bringToFront: function () {
          __bringToFront.call(this);
          this._textRedraw();
      },

      _textRedraw: function () {
            var textNodes = this._path.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('text'),
                tnIndex;

                    if (textNodes.length > 0) {
                for (tnIndex = textNodes.length - 1; tnIndex >= 0; tnIndex -= 1) {
                    textNodes[tnIndex].parentNode.removeChild(textNodes[tnIndex]);
              }
          }

          if (this.options.measurements) {
              this.setText();
          }
      },

      setText: function () {
            var path = this._path,
                points = this.getLatLngs(),
                pathSeg,
                prevPathSeg,
                center,
                angle,
                rotation,
                textNode;

          /* 
           * If not in SVG mode or Polyline not added to map yet return
           * setText will be called by onAdd, using value stored in this._text
           */
          if (!L.Browser.svg || typeof this._map === 'undefined') {
              return this;
          }

          for (pathSeg = 0; pathSeg < path.pathSegList.length; pathSeg += 1) {
                if (pathSeg > 0) {
                    prevPathSeg = path.pathSegList[pathSeg - 1];
                  center = this._calcCenter(
                      prevPathSeg.x,
                      prevPathSeg.y,
                      path.pathSegList[pathSeg].x,
                      path.pathSegList[pathSeg].y
                  );                  
                  angle = this._calcAngle(
                      prevPathSeg.x,
                      prevPathSeg.y,
                      path.pathSegList[pathSeg].x,
                      path.pathSegList[pathSeg].y
                  );
                  rotation = 'rotate(' + angle + ' ' + 
                        center.x + ',' + center.y + ')';
                  debugger;
                  textNode = document
                        .createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
                  textNode.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'middle');
                  textNode.setAttribute('x', center.x);
                  textNode.setAttribute('y', center.y);
                  textNode.setAttribute('transform', rotation);
                  textNode.textContent = points[pathSeg - 1]
                        .distanceTo(points[pathSeg]);

                  this._path.parentElement.appendChild(textNode);
              } else {
                    continue;
              }
          }
      },

      _calcCenter: function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
            return {
            x: (x1 + x2) / 2,
            y: (y1 + y2) / 2
          }
      },

      _calcAngle: function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
              return Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;
      },

      _updatePath: function () {
          __updatePath.call(this);
          this._textRedraw();
      }
  });
})();
```

Comment: there will be a new API https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/#InterfaceSVGPathData and a polyfill for that https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill
as well as a polyfill for the old API https://github.com/progers/pathseg Also see the official chromium bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=539385

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/p8fgcab5/) is the updated version of my fiddle.

Answer (score 21):

@holger-will gave some very useful links.

You can modify your js code to use the [new API](https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/#InterfaceSVGPathData).

for example:
Use `var pathData = path.getPathData()` instead of old `var segs = path.pathSegList`;
Use `pathData[1].values[4]` instead of old `path.pathSegList.getItem(1).x`
Use `path.setPathData(pathData)` to update the path element instead of old `path.pathSegList.appendItem/insertItem/removeItem`

Include the [path-data-polyfill.js](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill) for browsers which have not supported the new API.
(Chrome 50 still has not implemented `getPathData` and `setPathData`. There may be a long way...)

Here is a code sample:

```js
//svg code:
//...
//<path d="M0,0 L100,50" id="mypath"></path>
//<script href="/js/path-data-polyfill.js"></script>
//...

//js code:
var path = document.getElementById('mypath');
var pathdata = path.getPathData();
console.log(pathdata);
console.log(pathdata.length); //2
console.log(pathdata[0].type); //"M"
console.log(pathdata[0].values); //[0,0]
console.log(pathdata[1].type); //"L"
console.log(pathdata[1].values); //[100,50]
pathdata.push({type: "C", values: [100,-50,200,150,200,50]}); //add path segment
path.setPathData(pathdata); //set new path data
console.log(path.getAttribute('d')); //"M0,0 L100,50 C100,-50,200,150,200,50"
```

path data polyfill: https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill

Comment: Chrome 78 still does not support this? I am getting "getPathData is not a function" error

Comment: Still unsupported in Chrome 88.

Comment: Just to continue the tradition: Chrome 93 still does not implement it. Makes you wonder why they remove an API if they don't provide a proper alternative...

Comment: July'22 Chrome 103 - No support

Comment: @ackh Maybe the Chrome developers want people to use the polyfill rather than the old API, so that transitioning to the new API in the future is easier.

Comment: @root If that is the case, it is just bad practice. You're forcing *every* website that wants to use this API to include its own implementation instead of making the engine that runs your website provide it. If they think the API is bad, provide a better one and *then* deprecate the one you perceive as bad.

Comment: @ackh If they keep the old API, some people will use it, and their websites will break when/if the old API gets deprecated. This argument holds even if the definition or implementation of the new API isn't yet finalized. So using the polyfill (or directly a "non-API" technique such as [`path.setAttribute('d',...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8125957/5231110), which has disadvantages but at least isn't likely to get deprecated) makes the website more future-proof.