# PathSegList is deprecated and removed in Chrome 48

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

In Chrome 48, PathSegList is removed. And as I read in the answers to another question *"[Alternative for deprecated SVG pathSegList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352624/alternative-for-deprecated-svg-pathseglist)"*, Chrome is providing a new API, but I guess this new API is not yet available. What is another alternative and how can I use it. I know this is duplicate, but the link I mentioned is not helping me.

Comment: Why does the polyfill mentioned in one of the linked answers not help you?

Comment: ok . Now I have added poly-data-polyfill.js in my app. But what is replacement for SVGPathSeg.PATHSEG_MOVETO_REL , createSVGPathSegMovetoAbs and other similar constants and APIs ?

Comment: The polyfill defines replacements. https://github.com/progers/pathseg/blob/master/pathseg.js#L20

Comment: do I need to add pathSeg.js too ?

Comment: What do you mean *too*? Did you read the polyfill documentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative for deprecated SVG pathSegList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352624/alternative-for-deprecated-svg-pathseglist)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need path seg polyfill (pathSeg.js).

With [path data polyfill](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill.js), you can edit path data as a common array object.

Use [path data polyfill](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill.js) to work with new API. It's recommended.

```js
var path = document.querySelector('path'); //your <path> element
//Be sure you have added the pathdata polyfill to your page before use getPathData
var pathdata = path.getPathData();
console.log(pathdata);
/*
  you will get an Array object contains all path data details
  like this:
    [
        { "type": "M", "values": [ 50, 50 ] },
        { "type": "L", "values": [ 200, 200 ] }
    ]
*/

//replacement for createSVGPathSegMovetoRel and appendItem
pathdata.push({ type: 'm', values: [200, 100] });
path.setPathData(pathdata);

//replacement for createSVGPathSegMovetoAbs and appendItem
pathdata.push({ type: 'M', values: [300, 120] });
path.setPathData(pathdata);

//replacement for createSVGPathSegLinetoAbs and appendItem
pathdata.push({ type: 'L', values: [400, 120] });
path.setPathData(pathdata);

console.log(path.getAttribute('d'));

//create a new path data array
var pathdata = [
    { "type": "M", "values": [50, 50] },
    { "type": "L", "values": [200, 200] }
];
path.setPathData(pathdata);
console.log(path.getAttribute('d'));
```