# Uncaught TypeError: ia.createSVGPathSegLinetoAbs is not a function

Tags: svg, editor

After Chrome browser got updated to 48.0 version I am facing this issue where I am not able to load my **svg editor**.In my console window I can find the message "**Uncaught TypeError: ia.createSVGPathSegLinetoAbs is not a function** " I have followed the suggestions given at this earlier post [Alternative for deprecated SVG pathSegList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352624/alternative-for-deprecated-svg-pathseglist/35217435#35217435)  but request someone to please give a detail description of the fix for this issue. Also please suggest me the steps  to include pollyfill.js if thats the fix for this issue .

Answer (score 2):

The instructions on the polyfill page tell you what to do.

Copy the polyfill JS file to your webserver.  Then add the script tag to your HTML page (or your SVG file).

`<script src="pathseg.js"></script>`

Is there some other problem preventing you from doing this?

Comment: what does the line " <script src="pathseg.js"></script>" specify ? and am I suppose to create a pathseg.js file anywhere ?

Comment: I dont find any file named "pathseg.js" in my  svgedit project which I am working . Am i suppose to create this file and then give its reference using the script tag ?

Comment: A polyfill is third-party code written to fill gaps in a browsers functionality. It is not part of svgedit.  Download the polyseg.js file from the [polyfill site](https://github.com/progers/pathseg).  The direct link to the actual file is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/progers/pathseg/master/pathseg.js

Comment: Thank you Mr Paul for your suggestion . Now i have placed pathseg.js in my svgedit folder and I have included the <script src="pathseg.js"></script> line in my svg-editor.xhtml file .Still it isn't working . Any other steps  to be followed or files to be edited ? or any code change to be done .?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience Mr Paul . The issue is resolved . Actually it was my fault that I included the script in svg-editor.xhtml instead of svg-editor.html. Thanks for your help .