# Changing the X and Y coordinates of a SVG path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

How can I get the X and Y coordinates of a path in jQuery and then change them? I wanting to be able to animate my icon on click. I know there are other ways but  would like to use jQuery

```html
<svg class="path" style="height: 32px; width: 32px;">
  <g style="stroke: #ff6633; stroke-width: 4px;" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round">
    <path d="M2 4 L30 4" />
    <path d="M2 16 L30 16" />
    <path d="M2 28 L30 28" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: read the d attribute, parse the two values after the M. There are much much easier ways though.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you. Do you have a example?

Answer (score 2):

Change the `path` attribute to `newPath` using `.attr("d", newPath);` with JQuery.

Here's and example where each single path has a `click` event attached to it.
You can use any string manipulation method for changing the attribute `d` in the path.

#### Manipulate single path

```js
// click event on a path element of the SVG
$('path').click(function() {
  var path = $(this).attr("d");
  // just as an example, substitute the first two characters in d ("M2") with "M20"
  path = "M20" + path.slice(2); // here you manipulate the path as a string
  console.log(path); // check new path in the console
  $(this).attr("d", path);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg class="path" style="height: 32px; width: 32px;">
  <g style="stroke: #ff6633; stroke-width: 4px;" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round">
    <path d="M2 4 L30 4" />
    <path d="M2 16 L30 16" />
    <path d="M2 28 L30 28" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

#### Change all paths

This example shows you how to make the `svg` clickable and select all children paths in the `svg`. If you want to select a specific path, you can add an id to it.

```js
// select the svg element
$('svg').click(function() {
  $(this).find("path").each(function(index) {
    var d = $(this).attr("d");
    d = "M" + 10 * index + d.slice(2); // manipulate path 
    $(this).attr("d", d);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg class="path" style="height: 32px; width: 32px;">
  <g style="stroke: #ff6633; stroke-width: 4px;" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round">
    <path d="M2 4 L30 4" />
    <path d="M2 16 L30 16" />
    <path d="M2 28 L30 28" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I asked for but I don't understand a couple things. What is this line doing exactly? path = "M20" + path.slice(2);

Comment: And how can I select different coordinates? Say I want to change L30 4 on the first line to L30 30

Comment: @Reece They are just doing string manipulation. If you want to understand what the `slice()` function does to a string, [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).  If you want to manipulate other coordinates, then you can use many and various string manipulation functions in Javascript.

Comment: You can also access the path segments of the `d` attribute using the [`pathSegList` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#paths-InterfaceSVGAnimatedPathData) of the `<path>` element.  But note that you may have to use a [polyfill in some browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352624/alternative-for-deprecated-svg-pathseglist).