# Manipulating an array with map function in a reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, ecmascript-6, redux

I have implemented an action to increment each value of my ***path d*** in my ***svg***

In the Component

```
<button onClick={this.props.increase.bind(null, i)}>Increase</button>
```

The action

```
export function increase(index) {
  return {
    type: 'INCREMENT_COORDINATES',
    index
  }
}
```

The Reducer

```
case 'INCREMENT_COORDINATES' :
  console.log("incrementing coornidates")
  const a = action.index;
  debugger
  return state[a].d.map(x => {
    return x * 2;
  })
```

I get the error

**Uncaught TypeError: state[a].d.map is not a function**

See the screenshot

[image]

What am i doing wrong and how can i fix it?, i am returning the array of my path d in my action but then i can not map those values

Answer (score 1):

`state[a].d` is a string. Strings don't have the `map` function in their prototype. Checkout this thread if you need to parse the path coordinates using the string representation - [Extract x,y coordinates from arbitrary SVG path with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832534/extract-x-y-coordinates-from-arbitrary-svg-path-with-javascript).