# Set svg path data with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

My problem is when I want to set the `d`(data) attribute of an path element via `setAttribute("d","mySvgPathData");` or `.attr("d","mySvgPathData");` there is an unexpected token by `..."d",` **here** `"mySvgPathData"...`. 
The purpose of all this is that i want to contour a div with an svg graphic and have a bit of space in between. Both with rounded edges and it has to be responsive. So I thought I'll just create a function that makes the path fit to the viewport by including some variables in the path data. e.g. `M _myVar,0 c20,0...`, and so on.

Here is a screenshot of what I am planning:

[image: Illustrator Artboard]

[Here is the project I am working on (CodePen)](https://codepen.io/sanojLeOne/full/eBoQGr/).

I recreated the situation:

```js
$(document).ready(kontResize);

function kontResize() {
  $(".path").attr("d", "M1486,25c13.8,0,25,11.2,25,25v764c0,13.8-11.2,25-25,25H50c-13.8,0-25-11.2-25-25V50c0-13.8,11.2-25,25-25H1486 M1486,0H50C22.4,0,0,22.4,0,50v764c0,27.6,22.4,50,50,50h1436c27.6,0,50-22.4,50-50V50C1536,22.4,1513.6,0,1486,0L1486,0z
 ");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <path class="path" d="M 90,0 V90 H10 V10 H90 Z" />
</svg>
```

---

I would have commented on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053487/scripting-path-data-in-svg-reading-and-modifying/8125957#8125957?newreg=af8ec739a59e42a1b3db317b9c016f0f) post but I dont have 50 rep :(

I have searched the internet for two days now but with out any success

Comment: Seems like something wrong with your "mySvgPathData", Is this variable starts with M? I assume you have something like: var mySvgPathData = 'M'+_myVar+'0 c20,0...'. Am I right?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: @Leonid Lazaryev I posted a code snippet with the actual data I used.
Idk but is a compound path a problem because it works just fine if I put directly in to the html file?

Comment: @ Robert Longson: Did so !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had bad selector there and string was braked with new line, here is working example:

```js
$(document).ready(kontResize);

function kontResize() {
  $("path").attr("d", "M1486,25c13.8,0,25,11.2,25,25v764c0,13.8-11.2,25-25,25H50c-13.8,0-25-11.2-25-25V50c0-13.8,11.2-25,25-25H1486 M1486,0H50C22.4,0,0,22.4,0,50v764c0,27.6,22.4,50,50,50h1436c27.6,0,50 22.4,50-50V50C1536,22.4,1513.6,0,1486,0L1486,0z");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <path class="path" d="M 90,0 V90 H10 V10 H90 Z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank You Sir !!
But why is it bad though it works fine if I use it else where ?

Comment: @sanojLeOne it is how things done in javascript, you can not write string in 2 lines.
If You do so, you have to use plus sign: 
var a = 'Hello'+
' World'

Answer (score 3):

Are you actually using `setAttribute("d","mySvgPathData")`? Because that puts the *string value* `"mySvgPathData"` rather than the content of the `mySvgPathData` variable into `d`. Try `setAttribute("d", mySvgPathData)` instead.

Btw. you're having typos in your portfolio text: "wast" -> "vast", "soft ware" -> "software".

Comment: Thx for correcting the typos (not my mother language)
I recreated the error and checked if that was the error put unfortunately no.